# How to avoid trailing nul characters when writing with o_direct?

Tags: go, unix, io

I'm trying to do `o_direct` writes to my SSD and to do that I need to align my writes to block size which introduces unwanted nul characters. How can I avoid to write those unwanted nul characters?
At the moment i'm using `ftruncate` but it's bad, because it's slower and trashes the SSD. I would prefer to avoid writing those character at all.

Here's an example with DD:

`dd if=/dev/random bs=18 count=1 of=binfile oflag=direct`
Any block size different than 512 or multiples will fail, thus introducing unwanted characters if we want less than 512 bytes.

Here's an example with golang:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/sys/unix"
    "unsafe"
)

func Alignment(block []byte, AlignSize int) int {
    return int(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&block[0])) & uintptr(AlignSize-1))
}

func main() {

    BlockSize := 512
    AlignSize := 512

    path := "/path/to/file.txt"
    fd, err := unix.Open(path, unix.O_RDWR|unix.O_DIRECT, 0666)
    defer unix.Close(fd)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    message := []byte("Hello world\n")


    file := make([]byte, 512*2)

    a := Alignment(file, AlignSize)

    offset := 0
    if a != 0 {
        offset = AlignSize - a
    }

    file = file[offset : offset+BlockSize]

    copy(file, message)

    fmt.Println(file, a, offset, len(file))

    _, readErr := unix.Write(fd, file)

    //err = unix.Ftruncate(fd, len(message))
    
    if readErr != nil {
        panic(readErr)
    }

}
```

`file.txt` will have `Hello world\nNULNULNUL....` inside.

Comment: Opening the file using `O_DIRECT`, you can only write compete blocks. If you really must, I would write all except the last incomplete block, close the file, reopen without `O_DIRECT` and write the remainder.

Comment: unfortunately the kernel docs specifically mention that it's a bad idea to mix direct and buffered IO.

Comment: I think "mixing" refers to doing the 2 at the same time (having the file opened twice with different modes). I'm suggesting to do one after the other.

Comment: @icza, a nitpick: the [`open(2)`](https://manpages.debian.org/2/open) explicitly states that on newer kernels the only requirement for `O_DIRECT` is proper alignment: «Under Linux 2.4, transfer sizes, and the alignment of the user buffer and the file offset must all be multiples of the logical block size of the filesystem. Since Linux 2.6.0, alignment to the logical block size of the underlying storage (typically 512 bytes) suffices.». But still, I think you're correct in your assessment.

Comment: While we're at it, I'd recommend to sort of "reverse" your approach to obtaining properly aligned blocks by actually allocating in complete blocks: <https://go.dev/play/p/O9N2gUqPUi5>. Of course, this approach does not work for the general case when you first query the device underlying your filesystem for its natural block size so that it's only known at runtime.